# Function in gsub replacement

Tags: r, regex, string, substring

Is it possible to apply function in `gsub` replacement phrase ? Let's say after `str_to_title` we have

`This Is One Hell Of A Blahblah Cake`

I would like ignore certain words from the effect of `str_to_title` function, so that I would have

```
This is one Hell of a blahblah Cake
```

I am aware that str_to_title has its own list of exception, but I would like to customize that list by reverting some phrase back to lowercase.

My approach at the moment is

```
gsub("( Is | One | BlahBlah )", tolower("\\1"), str_to_title(x))
```

but `gsub` will not see the `tolower` function. An idea how t achieve this ? How can we replace regex with a function acting on the matched string ?

Comment: Are you sure they were lowercase in the first place? You should not follow this approach. You may just use the `tools::toTitleCase` code and modify it by adding your exceptions.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the package **gsubfn**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefix the replacement with [`\\L`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html) to convert them to lower case:

```
s = "This Is One Hell Of A Blahblah Cake"

gsub("(\\bIs\\b|\\bOne\\b|\\bBlahblah\\b)", "\\L\\1", s, perl = T)
# [1] "This is one Hell Of A blahblah Cake"
```

Or as commented @joran, you can use `gsubfn` package:

```
library(gsubfn)
options(gsubfn.engine = "R")
gsubfn("\\bIs\\b|\\bOne\\b|\\bBlahblah\\b", ~ tolower(x), s)
# [1] "This is one Hell Of A blahblah Cake"
```

Comment: `gsub("(\\b(Is|One|Blahblah)\\b", "\\L\\1", s, perl = T)` will also do. I'd put ignore.case=T to cover larger scope. And `perl=T` must be there for it to work. Can you shed some light on this `perl=T` ?

Comment: Agree `\\b(Is|One|Blahblah)\\b` is a more concise one. And `perl=TRUE` allows you use *PCRE regular expressions library* as from the [documentation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html), which is usually more powerful than base R regex engine. In this case, we need `perl=TRUE` to use `\\L` modifier.

Comment: @Kenny `\L` operator is not part of PCRE, it is an extension built into the PCRE library for R. It is implemented in Boost regex library that is based on PCRE.