# How to replace some characters after the last dot with their lower cases

Tags: r, regex

A simple question but I cannot solve it. I got a string like this mail address:

```
ma <- "something@somewhere.COM"
```

My goal is to get:

```
"something@somewhere.com"
```

So to put the to lower cases the part after the last dot. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077996/function-in-gsub-replacement), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178196/lower-case-certain-words-r), so I tried:

```
gsub(".*\\.","\\L\\1", ma, perl = T) 
[1] "COM" # nope
```

Also something like:

```
library(gsubfn)
options(gsubfn.engine = "R")
gsubfn(".*\\.", ~ tolower(x), ma)
[1] "something@somewhere.COM" # nope
```

I'm quite confused because it seems I can fetch the part I want to replace:

```
gsub(".*\\.","", ma)
[1] "COM"
```

But I cannot replace it properly. If you can give an explanation with the solution, I'll gladly appreciate it, regex is not my strongest feature.

Comment: Maybe try the `tolower`-function?

Comment: @Jaap tolower is going to work on the full string, I need to get the lower cases only for characters after the last dot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\\L` & `\\U` apply to a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) -- your first attempt is close but doesn't say which group to apply the command to:

```
ma <-"something@somewhere.COM"
gsub('(.*\\.)(.*)$', '\\1\\L\\2', ma, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "something@somewhere.com"
```

Note we capture two groups -- the part *before* (and including) the `.`, which we leave alone; and the part *after* the `.`, which we move to lower-case.

Also note it may be safer to use this regex to prevent any issues with greedy matching of `.`:

```
gsub('(.*\\.)([^.]*)$', '\\1\\L\\2', ma, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "something@somewhere.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply that to the second group of an email address, you could use an email like pattern with 2 capturing groups and use `\\L` for the second group.

```
([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.)([^\s@]+)
```

For example

```
gsub("([^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.)([^\\s@]+)","\\1\\L\\2", "something@somewhere.COM", perl = T)
```

Output

```
[1] "something@somewhere.com"
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/fkJWdg) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/faGWhc/1)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to  capture group and make use of `\\L` to change it to lowercase

```
sub("\\.(.*)$", ".\\L\\1", ma, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "something@somewhere.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

The part after the @ in an email address is case insensitive so you could convert the entire part after @ to lower case without any problems.

We consider both cases.

### Convert everything after last dot to lower case

To use `gsubfn` be sure that the regular expression is matching the extension.

Alternately we can make use of `file_ext` in the tools package (where the tools package comes with R so no installation is required).

A third approach is to use `file_path_sans_ext` together with `file_ext` (both from tools) and remove any trailing dot in case there was no extension.  If we knew there is always an extension then the `sub` part can be omitted.

(Of course if we know that the part before the extension has no upper case characters or if we don't mind that it is converted to lower case we could just apply `tolower` to the entire input.)

```
s <- "something@somewhere.COM"

# 1
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\.[^.]*$", tolower, s)
## [1] "something@somewhere.com"

# 2
library(tools)
ext <- file_ext(s)
sub(paste0(ext, "$"), tolower(ext), s)
## [1] "something@somewhere.com"

# 3
library(tools)
sub("\\.$", "", paste(file_path_sans_ext(s), tolower(file_ext(s)), sep = "."))
## [1] "something@somewhere.com"
```

### Convert everything after @ to lower case

As mentioned earlier the domain, i.e. the portion of the string after the @ character, is case insensitive so we can convert that entire part to lower case.  This is a simpler problem as we are guaranteed that there is only one instance of @. We use `gsubfn` in (4), extract the parts before and after the @ in (5) and use `read.table` without any regular expressions in (6).

```
s <- "something@somewhere.COM"

# 4
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("@.*", tolower, s)
## [1] "something@somewhere.com"

# 5
paste(sub("@.*", "", s), tolower(sub(".*@", "", s)), sep = "@")
## [1] "something@somewhere.com"

# 6
with(read.table(text = s, sep = "@", as.is = TRUE), paste(V1, tolower(V2), sep = "@"))
## [1] "something@somewhere.com"
```